# C# Blazor: Browser Support for .NET 7 in Clientside WebApp (WebAssembly)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have to update my project to **.NET 7** and I try to understand how .NET in Browsers (Blazor WebAssembly) work, because I'm not sure if I should update only the server or also the client. So:

1. If the API (Server) has .NET 7 and the Client (Blazor WebAssembly) still uses .NET 6, there shouldn't be any problems right? Because the Client shouldn't really care about the architecture of the API.
2. Does the Browser OR the Client (Blazor WebAssembly) deliver the .NET 7 libraries? So if I update the client to .NET 7, do I risk older browsers or older browser verions to not work anymore with my WebApp?

Sure I would prefer to have the same .NET in client and server, but I don't want to risk issues with older browsers / versions.

Comment: Using .NET 6 or .NET 7 won't affect if it's supported by browsers, since it's webassembly. If the browser supports webassembly or not will have an impact.

Comment: So the .NET libraries are included in the WebAssembly and the Client have to download it anyway?

Comment: @fredrik hate to nitpick but that's not 100% true because there's a lot more going on in Blazor than just Webassembly, even client-side. The browser-side Javascript in what was formerly known as the Mono WASM SDK - which does all the scaffolding and interop - is extensive and not guaranteed to work on out-of-date browser versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know there are two kinds of possible server applications when it comes to Blazor - there can be a pure API server that just handles CRUD and other stateless operations, and there can ALSO (but need not) be a hosting server from which the Blazor SPA is downloaded.

If you're talking about a pure API server - which it sounds like you are - it really doesn't matter that the .NET versions match. Indeed the API server could be based on any platform - Node.js, etc.

However, if you are indeed talking about the hosting server, that DOES need to be on the same .NET version as the client project. In hosted webassembly Blazor the hosting server is the source for the browser to download not just your WASM payload but the WASM .NET runtime and the supporting .JS files. You'll find that both the client project and hosting project (in the `dotnet` templates) reference the Blazor assemblies. If these don't match you could very easily run into compatibility problems.

Regarding your second question, the server delivers the Blazor libraries to the browser. Whether or not this is an actual ASP.NET Core hosting server, or just a static file server, all the files necessary to run your Blazor app are coming from a server and yes, the client has to download it. No modern browser has a built-in .NET runtime (webassembly or otherwise) (I say modern because IE might have, but that's rather irrelevant).

Could you run into a compatibility problem with older browsers by upgrading the .NET Blazor version? Yes, you COULD, but as long as your users are keeping their browsers updated, you SHOULDN'T. Officially Blazor supports the "latest" version of all modern browsers. I know from experience that that team makes lots of changes in the supporting .JS framework with each major version. Normally these are transparent to the Blazor developer, but they could easily introduce a change that breaks - say - an earlier version of Safari because of some obscure Javascript issue. (I'm picking on Safari because that's the one that is hardest for folks to keep updated because it usually means an OS upgrade too).

Comment: Thank you, this was the exact information I was missing. And I missed the hosting point, so yes the mentioned API is also the host for the blazor app.

Comment: Great. Yeah in my app I actually have a totally separate API server from the Blazor hosting server and it was exactly because (until a year ago) my API server was on Framework and it was a lot harder to migrate that to .NET6 than the Blazor project.